# Steps to be followed for creating a build.gradle file in corda project

Tags: corda

What documentation should we follow for creating a build.gradle file in corda project if the project is created from scratch rather than using templates available in github

Comment: modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using one of the templates, to be honest. But, documentation on this subject can be found here:

https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html